# com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0

Tags: android-studio

Ayuden tengo el mismo error, pero creo que ya no me valida el codigo.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

solo me deja usar esta opción

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar la clase:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

debes definir la dependencia:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

---

Te recomiendo convertir tu proyecto a Android X, ya que lo ideal es dejar de usar las clases de soporte, para esto ve al menù de Android Studio:

`Refactor` - `Migrate to AndroidX`

Comment: Verdad, estaba usando una clase antigua, si me funciono con implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"

Comment: Excelente @ErickValverde actualmente hay que dejar de usar las clases de soporte, debemos usar únicamente Android X , saludos.